# How to set up a constructor for a Iterator class with a stack?

Tags: java, constructor, stack, binary-search-tree, nodes

I need help setting up this constructor for my Iterator class. The directions are as follows:

The constructor should create a new stack and push its node parameter onto it, followed by
all left children accessible from the parameter. Consider a case in which the tree consists
only of left children (essentially a linked list). The node with the highest value (root) would
be pushed first and be on the bottom of the stack, followed by its left child just above it in the
stack, followed by its left child, and so on until the leaf, which would contain the lowest value
in the tree. When popping nodes from the stack, they would contain values from lowest to
highest… an in-order traversal.

I am not sure how to create a new stack with the node in the parameter being a type BSTNode type.

Here is my code:

```
public static class Iterator<E>
    {
        private Stack<BSTNode<E>> stack;

        public Iterator(BSTNode<E> node)
        {

        }
        public boolean hasNext()
        {
            if(stack.peek() != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        public E next()
        {
            stack.pop();
            E value;
            value = (E) stack.pop();
            return value;
        }
    }
```

As of right now, just ignore the other two methods, I just need help with the Iterator method. I'll figure those out later. Thank you.

I found out my problem was in a different class and method. I set it up as this and I want to know if this is the correct way of doing it.

The instructions for this method is

*to create and return an instance of the static nested Iterator class that will be used to iterate through the elements in the tree. The tree's root should initially be passed to the iterator constructor.*

Here is the following code I did for that method:

```
 public Iterator<E> iterator()
    {
        return new Iterator<>(root);
    }
```

root is the top of the binary search tree. It is in that class as a private variable.

Comment: `this.stack = new Stack<>()`. That's what allows constructing a new stack and assigning it to the stack variable.

Comment: @JBNizet I actually tried that, however I need to use the node in the parameter.

Comment: Well, follow the instructions. Now that you have a stack, you can add elements to it. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#push-E-

Comment: @JBNizet That was just what a stack is. I need help on my constructor. How to implement that node in the parameter that is a different type to have it fit into my stack..

Comment: The iterator only needs next() and hasNext().  And it should not destroy the data structure  it is iterating over (in your case, the Stack). Since Stack extends Vector should should be able to iterate over it accessing the inherited methods. And if the class is a private one inside another class, you shouldn't need a constructor.

Comment: @jim829 the iterator doesn't iterate through a Stack. It iterates over nodes of a binary search tree.

Comment: *How to implement that node in the parameter that is a different type to have it fit into my stack*: I have no idea of what you mean by that. The stack is a Stack<BSTNode<E>>. So it can contain elements of type BSTNode<E>. And the elements you need to add are of type BSTNode<E>. So, what's the problem?

Comment: @JB Nizet.  Thanks for the clarification.  I was focused more on his code than his description.

Comment: @JBNizet so up above, I have what the constructor should include and what it's looking for. I am merely asking how could I create this constructor that can fit that criteria..

Comment: And you got the answer. You need to create a new stack. I posted the code to do that You need to assign it to the stack variable. i posted the code to do that. You need to push the node assed as argument to it. I linked to the method you can use to do that. I won't do your homework. Try to at least do that. Then read the instructions carefully and use a loop to add the other elements you need to add.

Comment: @JBNizet I did exactly what you said, but it's still not solving my error that I am receiving when I run my tests.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm going to keep working on it, I'll let you know if I have any further questions.

Comment: @JBNizet my apologies, my error was taking place in a different method, but I appreciate your help. It worked.

Comment: I posted what worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I set it up.

This is just the public that is above the class. Not inside the class. I just return a new Iterator with root being the top value.

```
public Iterator<E> iterator()
    {
        return new Iterator<>(root);
    }
```

Then inside the class below it, I create a new stack and have that stack push the nodes and the nodes to the left of it as long as it isn't null.

```
public static class Iterator<E>
    {
        private Stack<BSTNode<E>> stack;

        public Iterator(BSTNode<E> node)
        {
            this.stack = new Stack<>();
            while (node != null)
            {
                stack.push(node);
                node = node.left;
            }
        }
        public boolean hasNext()
        {
            return !stack.isEmpty();
        }
        public E next()
        {
            BSTNode<E> goodDays = stack.pop();
            E result = goodDays.data;
            if (goodDays.right != null)
            {
                goodDays = goodDays.right;
                while (goodDays != null)
                {
                    stack.push(goodDays);
                    goodDays = goodDays.left;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```